# Add build action from console?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I have a .NET Maui program and I want to add the `MauiIcon` build action to a replacement app icon in the `Resources/AppIcon` folder. In Visual Studio this easy: selecting the image in the solution explorer allows me to change the build action in the properties list.

But what change does this actually make in the files? I would like to manually add a build action from a text editor or the console, rather than Visual Studio. Is this possible?

Comment: have you looked at the `csproj` file to see what is different when you change the build action?

Comment: Thanks, found it! I'm new to both Maui and C# in general, so I really appreciate the direction on this.

Comment: glad you figured it out.  Please post your findings as an answer so others can benefit